# How to manage having two data sources without using the @Primary annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two data sources

1. Quartz
2. simple JPA

I would like them both to live in the same Spring based web application, 
so I have created two classes :

1.

```
@Configuration


public class QuartzDataSource {

@Bean
// @Primary
@Qualifier("quartzDataSourceProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="org.quartz.dataSource")
public DataSourceProperties quartzDataSourceProperties() {
    DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = new DataSourceProperties();
    return dataSourceProperties;
}

@Bean
//   @Primary
@Qualifier("quartzDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="org.quartz.dataSource")
public DataSource quartzdataSource( @Qualifier("quartzDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    DataSource build = dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    return build;
    }
}
```

2.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "JPAEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "JPATransactionManager",
    basePackages = {"com.schedulerservice"})
public class JpaDataSourceConfiguration {


@Bean
@Qualifier("taskStatusDataSourceProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties("task.status.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
    DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = new DataSourceProperties();
    return dataSourceProperties;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("taskStatusDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties("task.status.datasource")
public DataSource taskStatusDataSource(@Qualifier("taskStatusDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    return dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
   }

}
```

I tried on the Application

```
  @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

but with no successes and the error I am getting is

```
Parameter 0 of method dataSourceInitializer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 3 were found:
- dataSourceProperties: defined by method 'dataSourceProperties' in class path resource [com/schedulerservice/configuration/JpaDataSourceConfiguration.class]
- quartzDataSourceProperties: defined by method 'quartzDataSourceProperties' in class path resource [com/schedulerservice/configuration/quartz/QuartzDataSource.class]
- spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties: defined in null
```

When I am add the [`@Primary` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) everything works

**How can I avoid using the @Primary annotation?**

Comment: What do you get when excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration?

Comment: this example is with excluding , when unexcluding  same thing.

Comment: But at your class `JpaDataSourceConfiguration` you are using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` without excluding. If you are already using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` at your application level and it is in a root package you do not need to use it again. If so, you need to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration.